# Degree between vector and point

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have a vector and a point $(x, y)$. The vector starts from $(0, 0)$ and goes to $(x_1, y_1)$. $x$, $y$, $x_1$, $y_1$ are known. How can I get the degree that vector should rotate clockwise to face this point? [Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDWR3.png)

Comment: [Trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry); apply it to vector from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ to compute $\text {cos}(\theta)$ and find the angle $\theta$. The same for the other one, finding $\theta_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an another vector $\vec A$ which joins $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$. So now simply calculate the angle between this factor and your vector using dot product.
You have:
 $ cos \theta = \frac{xx_1+yy_1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}}$
Where $\theta$ is angle between the two vectors

Comment: This returns cosine of angle in range [0°; 180°] (smallest angle of two possible). How can I get only clockwise angle (in range [0°; 360°] or [-180°; 180°])?

Comment: This can be determined on the basis of in which quadrant do $(x,y)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ lie. So based on their relative position(you will have various cases), you can get the clockwise angle in terms of $\theta$ :)